# Getting server ID's from JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am wanting to get the server ID from a JSON file which I am confused on how to do. Below is my current Python file

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
import json

with open("configs/premium.json") as f:
    premium = json.load(f)

def premium(bot, message):
    id = message.server.id
    return premium.get(id)

class Play:
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def play(self, ctx):
        try:
            if ctx.message.server.id == premium:
                await self.client.say('Premium works')
            else:
                await self.client.say('Non-Premium Works!')
        except Exception as error:
            await self.client.say('{}'.format(error))

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Play(client))
```

JSON File

```
{"serverID":"498054637245693952"}
```

Comment: To begin with, your JSON file is not valid.  It should read {"serverID":"498054637245693952"} or something like that.  You have a value with no name

Comment: Hello, I've noticed you haven't accepted any answers to the questions you've been asking since you've joined SO. You should consider choosing an answer that helped you and accepting it so others can see the solution and so the people that helped you get recognition for their answers. Check out [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your JSON file is

> {"serverID":"498054637245693952"}

Then just replace

`with open("configs/premium.json") as f:
    premium = json.load(f)`

with

`with open("configs/premium.json") as f:
    premium = json.load(f)['serverID']`

Also, you should get rid of the `def premium(bot, message):` function or use a different name since it's interfering with your server ID variable name, ex.

[image]